# Group columns and store variables in list within dataset in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyverse

So basically, I have a dataframe like this

```
fruit       vendor   size
banana     Walmart      M
banana       Sears      L
apple     Popeye's      XL
orange  Footlocker      S
apple     Popeye's      W
banana     Walmart      L
```

And I need it to look like this (I tried a group_by but idk how to group sizes as a list in a row.

```
fruit       vendor   size
banana     Walmart      c("M", "L")
banana       Sears      L
apple     Popeye's      c("XL","W")
orange  Footlocker      S


#Tried this
df %>% 
  group_by(fruit, vendor) %>%
##now what?
```

Then later on I would like to choose from the list on an ifelse.

```
inc_list <- c("XS","S")
minc_list <- c("M","L", "W", "XL")
df$counter <- ifelse(unlist(df$size) %in% inc_list , 1, 0)
```

Doesnt work but I want it to look like. So :
if appears in inc_list then count in counter1 how many there are. Ditto for minc_list and counter2, counts how many of the ones in there are in that list.

```
fruit       vendor            size    counter1   counter2 
banana     Walmart      c("M", "L")         1          1
banana       Sears      L                   0          1
apple     Popeye's      c("XL","W")         0          2
orange  Footlocker      S                   1          0
```

EDIT: Last bit, c("S","S") would only be 1, duplicates from the same list shouldn't count.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(fruit, vendor) %>% summarise(size = list(size))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `size` into a list in `summarise` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(fruit, vendor) %>%summarise(size = list(size))

#   fruit  vendor     size     
#  <chr>  <chr>      <list>   
#1 apple  Popeyes    <chr [2]>
#2 banana Sears      <chr [1]>
#3 banana Walmart    <chr [2]>
#4 orange Footlocker <chr [1]>
```

You can also do this in base R :

```
aggregate(size~fruit+vendor, df, list)
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(size = list(size)), .(fruit, vendor)]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(fruit = c("banana", "banana", "apple", "orange", 
"apple", "banana"), vendor = c("Walmart", "Sears", "Popeyes", 
"Footlocker", "Popeyes", "Walmart"), size = c("M", "L", "XL", 
"S", "W", "L")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Nice! Yeah apoligies for the last minute add I wanted to get this posted soon but theres one last step I forgot, see updated OP.

Comment: @JohnThomas I think you have asked another question regarding this edited part.

Answer (score 0):

We can also convert to string with `toString`

```
aggregate(size~fruit+vendor, df, toString)
#   fruit     vendor  size
#1 orange Footlocker     S
#2  apple    Popeyes XL, W
#3 banana      Sears     L
#4 banana    Walmart  M, L
```